# Android: SQLite query with multiple OR wildcard operators

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I am working on an app that is pulling data from a SQL server using a stored procedure in a webservice. I'm dumping all the data into a SQLite database and running queries on the database to display in different list views in the app. I am also applying a filter to these views so that users have the option of searching the lists. The field I am using as a primary key field contains IDs which I do not need for all the views. Therefore, I am using queries to not display those particular records when required.

Most of the IDs are in categories and have similar names beginning with certain letters which I can include in wildcard queries. This way I can include a wildcard in a query using NOT LIKE and OR operators and not have to include the specific ID names which will make the query pretty long. This is the code I have below.

The first method is the filter method (`public Cursor fetchScheduleByDate(String inputText, String newConfDate)`). The second is the method called when the view is initially displayed (`public Cursor getAllSChedulesByConfDate(String newConfDate)`). Using the multiple NOT LIKE and OR operators in the queries is not working and the results set indicates that these statements are being ignored. If I use just one NOT LIKE operator it works. I can't figure this out.

```
public Cursor fetchScheduleByDate(String inputText, String newConfDate) throws SQLException {
           Log.w(TAG, inputText);
           Cursor mCursor = null;
           if (inputText == null  ||  inputText.length () == 0)  {
            mCursor = db.query(SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ID, KEY_functiontitle, KEY_fucntioindate, KEY_functionStartTime, KEY_functionEndTime, KEY_functiondescription, KEY_LOCATIONNAME},
                    KEY_fucntioindate + " = " + newConfDate + " AND (" + KEY_ID + " NOT LIKE 'EXHX%' OR " + KEY_ID + " NOT LIKE 'EXHV%')", null, null, null, null, null);
           }
           else {
            mCursor = db.query(true, SQLITE_TABLE, new String[] {
                    KEY_ID, KEY_functiontitle, KEY_fucntioindate, KEY_functionStartTime, KEY_functionEndTime, KEY_functiondescription, KEY_LOCATIONNAME},
                    KEY_functiontitle + " like '%" + inputText + "%' AND " + KEY_fucntioindate + " = " + newConfDate + " AND (" + KEY_ID + " NOT LIKE 'EXHX%' OR " + KEY_ID + " NOT LIKE 'EXHV%')", null, null, null, null, null);
           }
           if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
           }
           return mCursor;

          }


public Cursor getAllSChedulesByConfDate(String newConfDate){
             Cursor mCursor = db.query(SQLITE_TABLE,  new String[] {
                     KEY_ID, KEY_functiontitle, KEY_fucntioindate, KEY_functionStartTime, KEY_functionEndTime, KEY_functiondescription, KEY_LOCATIONNAME },
                     KEY_fucntioindate + " = " + newConfDate + " AND (" + KEY_ID + " NOT LIKE 'EXHX%' OR " + KEY_ID + " NOT LIKE 'EXHV%')", null, null, null, null, null);
             if (mCursor != null) {
                 mCursor.moveToFirst(); 
             }
             return mCursor;

         }
```

Comment: KEY_fucntioindate ..... is this right spelling of the key or it is KEY_fucntionindate

Comment: Yes, that is the right spelling. This is how the field name is spelled in the stored procedure and I just wanted to make it consistent.

Comment: ok I have given an example of a wild card query Does it help

Comment: wildcard should be inside a ""

Comment: It's not the same. That question I realized what I was doing wrong and fixed it.

Comment: I decided to use the LIKE operator instead for IDs I want displayed instead of using the NOT LIKE operator for IDs I do not want displayed, and that worked fine. I guess for some reason SQLite does not like my application of the NOT LIKE operator when used multiple times in a query. Go figure.